# Any reason to compute an INT for a constant?

Tags: c#, constants

In another part of the pasketti code I've inherited, I came across this:

```
public const int SqlCommandTimeout = 60 * 10;
```

Is there any reason why this should be a calculated value that is then placed into a constant?

My C# training has all been on-the-job with a book or two for backup, so for all I know there could have been a valid reason for this.

Comment: I would personally have put the 600 with a comment descriptor. Making the compiler do an extra step simply for readability seems a little off. But hey, that's just me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's just intended to be more readable: 60 * 10 = 10 minutes.

Comment: Yes. The compiler is going to do the calculation for you anyway, so it only makes a difference in the source code, to the reader.

Comment: ^ also known as **constant folding**, probably the most basic of compiler optimizations.

Comment: @kaplooeymom - FWIW, I usually add a comment indicating the units, e.g. `// Seconds.`  (I have run across a legitimate use of grams per square foot.)

Comment: @HABO there are hardly any comments in this 75 project solution, except for the occasional /// summary section, with only the title of the method filled in. We also received no documentation from the previous developers.

Answer (score 2):

Only to show the reasoning behind the constant value.  It seems like a long time, but if `SqlCommandTimeout` is in seconds, this is a good way to show it's 10 minutes instead of trying to figure out how many minutes there are in 600 seconds.